# Submit button not performing correct PHP functions

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

So I am having some trouble finding out why my submit button just happen to not perform the set of PHP functions I have given it. I want to store the information in my MySQL server using PDO. However, I also want to generate the article URL that the article will have. I do this by using the URL for the article folder I have and add on the title... afterwards I use a function to remove the spaces and add _ instead. This way it is a valid URL.
However, when I press the submit button, nothing happens. It simply just refreshes on the exact same page, and nothing has arrived in my database. Why is that?

**This is my PHP code for the folowing button:**

```
// BLOG POST UPLOAD
    else if (isset($_POST['addpost'])){

    $posttitle = $_POST['title'];
    $postcontent = $_POST['text'];

    $posturl = "http://www.myurlgoeshere.com/drottningborg/artikler/" . $postitle;
    $posturl = str_replace(' ', '_', $posturl);

    $blogquery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, post, url) VALUES (:posttitle,:postcontent,:posturl)");

    $blogquery->bindParam(':posttitle', $posttitle, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
    $blogquery->bindParam(':postcontent', $postcontent, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
    $blogquery->bindParam(':posturl', $posturl, PDO::PARAM_STR, 200);
    $blogquery->execute();

    header("Location: URL GOES HERE");
    }
```

**My form looks like this:**

```
<div id="newpost">
<form>
Tittel:
<br />
<input type="text" name="title" class="posttitle" value="Skriv tittel her...">
<br />
Tekst:
<br />
<textarea name="text" class="posttext">Skriv artikkel her...</textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="addpost" value="Lag artikkel">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<form action="function.php" method="POST">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the action and method on form

```
<form action="where_do_you_want" method="post">
```

**UPDATE:**

You also did the wrong name:

```
$posttitle = $_POST['title'];
```

and here you need to change:

```
$posturl = "http://www.myurlgoeshere.com/drottningborg/artikler/" . $postitle; // change with $posttitle
```

Comment: Of course.. thank you! Will accept answer when time has gone :)

Comment: My URL isn't generated properly, have I joined them correctly?

Comment: @FriedBitz You can also use `action=""` if you want to submit on the same page. Better this way, if all your code is in the same page.

Comment: change the action with your name of file... I write this only for example, because I dont know your file name

Comment: If you use the same file you can write only action="", if you use another file the PHP when you insert the post, you write the PHP name file.

Comment: I did that, its working to post, but my URL doesnt get generated correctly. I dont get what I want after the URL... just the URL... `...artikler/" . $postitle;` dont get the $posttitle

Comment: @ErmanBelegu The OP can also use `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` if everything is on the same page, if it's not an external call. As I stated above your comment, `action=""` does the same thing, however using `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` could be better as it may avoid code injection.

Comment: @FriedBitz I update the answer. I saw that you write not correct the name of `$posttitle` with `$postitle;`

Comment: @ErmanBelegu Instead of writing an answer as a "comment" `$postitle; // change with $posttitle`, I suggest you post a "before and after" method. I.e. "Here is what you had, this is what you should have", type of thing. Ambiguous.

Comment: @Fred thanks I lot for advice. I will do it always on future!

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post">
```

try this, I think should help